# Is singular barycentric subdivision injective?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

This question has been asked on mathstackexchange without any answers.

Let us note $\Delta_p(X)$ the $p$-singular chains on a topological space $X$. We have a well-known barycentric subdivision
$$b:Δ_p(X)→Δ_p(X).$$
Is $b$ injective ? Moreover, does $b$ have a retraction ? I think I can prove the injectivity if $X$ is a manifold, using integration of differential forms, but in the general case it is not very clear.

If necessary, one can assume that $X$ is Hausdorff and localy compact.

Answer (score 5):

No: consider the circle. Let $\sigma_1$ be the singular 1-simplex that wraps exactly once counterclockwise around the circle, and let $\sigma_2$ be obtained from $\sigma_1$ by reversing the orientation and rotating 180 degrees. Then $\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ is nontrivial, but the barycentric subdivision consists of four 1-simplices that cancel in pairs.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the cancellation in pairs occurs in homology but not in $\Delta_p$.

Comment: But if we don't reverse the orientation and only do a rotation of 180 degrees, then $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$ and $b(\sigma_1)=b(\sigma_2).$

Comment: If you don't reverse the orientation, nothing can cancel.

Comment: And I'm still pretty sure the cancellation happens as I originally said. Look, suppose $\sigma_1$ has its endpoints at $(1,0)$, embedding the circle in the plane in the standard way. Then the barycentric subdivision of $\sigma_1$ is the sum of the two CCW-oriented arcs between $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. Similarly, $\sigma_2$ has its endpoints at $(-1,0)$, and so is not $-\sigma_1$, but its subdivision is the sum of the two arcs oriented clockwise. So everything cancels as singular chains.